# Is one large whole house fan better than two smaller ones?

Tags: hvac

I'm having an addition put on my house and I'm considering the "[Quiet Cool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00THNS5ZS)" line of  whole house fans.  The fans are quite expensive and price wise two small fans are almost the same price as one larger fan.

My question - would two small fans (of say 750 CFM) be better be better than one large fan (of 1500 CFM)? Is there any benefit to having two fans in different locations of the house?

More Info:
The house is about 2,000 square feet split over two floors.  I have a low threshhold for noise

Comment: Does the larger fan have a speed control or is it just on or off?

Comment: I think it has speed control

Comment: Depends on the house. And the fans. And your tolerance for noise in the key locations. And.... My point is that the question isn't answerable as it is. It's broad and subjective.

Comment: I'd lean towards 1 fan.  I can't put my finger on it, but two fans seems like it could cause some odd patterns in the airflow.  Would you ever have the desire to close off a logical section of the house with doors an only use one fan?  I can't picture a good use case for that.

Comment: I agree with isherwood we don't know enough about the home layout other than 2 floors and 2000 sq ft. I might say 2 smaller ones to play devil's advocate but without a layout it's a total guess.

Comment: one advantage of two fan choice is that it allows for a failure of less than 100%

Comment: Two fans would fight each other for air and cfm would take a hit

Comment: Related : https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/164206/97780

Comment: I think the two fans fighting each other sounds right - can you make that an answer so I can award points?